# How to check if a String contains two same characters?

Tags: string, android-studio

In my case a string contains for example something like **2500.00**. Also you input a string in the same format for example 250.0 which would be converted to **250.00**. These strings will be converted to float and they will be added or subtracted.

Now I want to check if the string contains two "." somewhere for example 2.50.00 or 250..00. In that case an **errormessage** should be displayed.

Therefore my question is how am I able to check if a string contains two "." characters at any position of the string?

Comment: you can check both "." must not be one after another "."

Comment: `boolean containsTwoDots(String str) {
  return str.indexOf('.') != str.lastIndexOf('.');
}`

Comment: If you try to convert the string to a number (assuming that you're dealing with a decimal point here) then that should fail if you enter either "2.50.00" or "250..00". Trap that situation and report the error.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this worked perfect for me thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may check if a dot appears more than once in a string with a simple method checking if the first index of the char is not equal to the index of the last char occurrence:

```
boolean containsTwoDots(String str) { 
    return str.indexOf('.') != str.lastIndexOf('.'); 
}
```